# AWS EKS - service zonal aware routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

Curious - I was wondering when AWS will support this newly available alpha feature that was released in 1.17 called "Service Topology"? It looks like it is set as a feature-gate flag on the initial kube-api deployment as an argument - I created a new EKS cluster and viewed the Cloudwatch logs and I did not see it show up as a parameter that was specified.

I am hoping we can levearge this capability to make our services zonal aware - to assist in avoiding those excessive inter-zone transfer costs that can build up over time as data flow increases in a cluster.

Has anyone else experience this issue with your cluster? Any good tips to help alleviate some of the inter-zone cost pain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this out later on in that same week.  Any type of "alpha" feature in Kubernetes will not be readily available in AWS EKS until it is graduated to "beta".